# How do I run a background process in a menu program I've created using BASH?

Tags: bash, background-process

So, I've created a menu program which prompts you with a few choices on what you want to execute. Trouble is, I have to have option "b"that runs a process in the
background, a long sleep for example, so you get the menu 
back right away and can make other selections while the 
background job is running. I'm confused as to what process I'm supposed to have running in the background, in my professors example he says use sleep but when I put that into my case I dont't I got the correct results.

```
while [ true ]
do
    clear
    cat <<EOF

                        M A I N   M E N U
                       ========= =========

                                          $(date)
                        l> -- List all file names in current directory
                        o> -- sign on this session
                        f> -- sign off this session
                        c> -- check if a file exists and view its contents
                        b> -- background job
                        s> -- interactive shell
                        d> -- shows date

                        q> -- quit

                        Please choose....or else..
   EOF
   read ans

   case $ans in

        l) ls -a
           sleep 2
           ;;
        o) signon
           ;;
        f) signoff
           ;;
        c) chk
           sleep 2
           ;;
        b) sleep 10 &
           ;;
        d) date
           ;;
        q) break
           ;;
    esac
done
```

So this is probably easy for some of yall to figure out but I'm new to programming and I'm confused as hell. When I run the program, the first three choices execute just fine, my chk file doesnt work, I cant get the date to show up but more importantly is the background process doesnt seem to work. I think I'm misunderstanding processes and background jobs as a whole so any help or further explanation on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated ! Also, sorry for the code looking like crap on here, I havent really mastered how to get the code from my screen to the posts in one piece yet.
`

Comment: Did you really notice a 10 second delay after option `b` ? You might want to add some debug lines there: `ps -ef | grep "sleep 10"; sleep 4`. The `clear` might wipe away relevant information (`command not found`), debug without the `clear`.

Comment: So I was thinking about this ass backwards, again I'm really new to all of this so I appreciate you helping me and putting up with my obviously stupid questions. So yeah, of course if I put a sleep for 10 seconds in background I'm not going to be able to see it!! DUH! I created another option on the menu program that allows me to choose a new shell, then when I choose a new shell it starts up and, assuming before I started a new shell I chose "b" which runs sleep for 20 seconds in the background, I can 'ps' and see that the sleep is still running. So yay I figured it out thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

- No argument is passed to `chk`, which if it's a normal *nix tool would mean that it would wait indefinitely for some input followed by EOF (<kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd>). You might want to add an argument for it to read.
- `sleep` doesn't display anything, so if you want to see it running in the background you should open up another terminal and look for it in the process list:

  ```
  ps wafux | less
  ```

  (you can search in `less` by pressing `/` followed by your regular expression, such as simply `sleep`)
- To give yourself a better chance of seeing the process, you can change it to `sleep 1000`, `sleep 1d` or something similar. It takes an infinitesimally small amount of resources to keep a `sleep` process running, so don't worry about them piling up.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify that I created the chk program, it checks to see if a file exits, if it exists the file then the program preforms cat on the file and print it to the screen. When I run 'chk pizza' outside of the helper programmin (the menu program I'm working on) it works fine but when I put chk as a choice for choice c I get nothing in return. I will try a longer sleep ! Thank you

Comment: So change your menu to `chk pizza` or `read -p "Check what" file; chk "${file}"`.

Comment: Alright I'm going to try this, I was a little confused on what sleep really did and now I kinda feel stupid for expecting to see something printed to my screen while running sleep as a background process :/ anyway, I'm still stumped on how I'll get 'chk' to work but I will try what you have here for me thanks!

Comment: Using `read -p "Check what" file; chk "${file}"` worked !!! So freakin cool, thanks so much. So because I didn't have an argument for `chk` it just waited around forever huh? I guess that makes sense, still trying to wrap my head around all of this theory on why things work and dont work but I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

OP saw my comment and agreed that it was the problem:

When you put a `sleep` command to the background, it is hard to notice.
You can try to find it a moment after starting, or look with another terminal. A command with a longer sleep wil be found easier, such as `sleep 118`.